# Trying to trying to select images from a database and insert them into a Treeview

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, blob

I am trying to select images from a database with other info and insert them into a `Treeview`, and this `Treevire` has to be shown in a `notebook`,

I have tried the following code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import sqlite3
class Cardealer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root
        
# calling dashboad_checks so its showing the treeview on the root notebook
        self.dashboard_checks()

def dashboard_checks(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
        self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

        self.buying_checks_row = self.cursorObj.execute(
            'SELECT checkpic, buyername, carmake, checknum, checkvalue, checkdate FROM cars_selling_checksonly')
        self.buying_checks_output = self.cursorObj.fetchall()

        self.checkslist_buying_img = []
        for record in self.buying_checks_output:
            checks_buying_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(date=record[0])
            self.Dashboardcheck_buying_tree.insert("", 
            END,image=checks_buying_img,values=record[1:])
            self.checkslist_buying_img.append(checks_buying_img)

        self.con.commit()

    def selling_filedialogscheckonepic(self):
        global filename, img, images
        f_types = [("png", "*.png"), ("jpg", "*.jpg"), ("Allfile", "*.*")]
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=f_types)
        img = Image.open(filename)
        img = img.resize((700, 270), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        self.selling_checkimagelabel.place(x=20, y=60)
        self.selling_check_fob = open(filename, 'rb')
        self.selling_check_fob = self.selling_check_fob.read()
        self.selling_check_fob = (self.selling_check_fob)
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\thecardealer(new version)\main.py", line 3271, in <module>
    x = Cardealer()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\thecardealer(new version)\main.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.dashboard_checks()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\thecardealer(new version)\main.py", line 106, in dashboard_checks
    checks_buying_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(date=record[0])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 108, in __init__
    mode = Image.getmodebase(mode)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 294, in getmodebase
    return ImageMode.getmode(mode).basemode
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageMode.py", line 74, in getmode
    return _modes[mode]
KeyError: None
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000001FC7DA30E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would appreciate any help as I am a new programmer and still learning.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code, and try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that's not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok right now

Comment: @BryanOakley all Info now are important , I cant reduced anymore, if you can help me with it, I would appreciate it

Comment: error shows problem in line with `ImageTk.PhotoImage(date=record[0])` - so first you could use `print()` to check what you have in `record[0]`

Comment: do you have `image data` in database - you have `SELECT buyername, ...` so `record[0]`  can means `buyername` - and this doesn't sound like `image data` but like some `string`.

Comment: @furas Thank your for reply, I edited my code right now image in the database is checkpic and it is a blob in the database, I tried to print(record[0]) but i got the same error

Comment: did you print it before `ImageTk.PhotoImage(date=record[0])` ? Don't you get any information what is in this variable?

Comment: error shows also `return _modes[mode]  KeyError: None` which may suggest that it need `mode` and maybe it means if image is `RGB`, `GRAYSCALE` or `B&W`

Comment: @furas i got this now after printing it :
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\x00\x00d\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00L\xe4\xe8\\\x00\x00\x13kIDATx\x9c\xed\x9di\x98\x14\xd5\xd5\xc7\xcf\xb9\xf7VU\xf7\xf4\xf4\xcc40*\x04\x15\x02.\xb8\x80\x1b\n\x88\t\x88\x0bn\xd1hD\x10E\x04\x15\x95E\x83\n\x8a"hD\x14\x8c\x0b\x82&\xc8\xa2FApy\xd5\xc7\xedQ\xe3\x96\x10\x891&1\x12\x97\x88\xcb\x0b\x8a\xa20{wW\xd5\xbd\xf7\xbc\x1fjf\x18\xa0\xa7A\xac\xaa\xe9\x9e\xb7~_\xe8\xa1\xfb\xa9[\xd5\xfd\xaf{\xce=\xe7\xdcS\x98N\xa7!"\xc2oX[\x9f@D\xfb

Comment: it shows that you have PNG - so it is OK.

Comment: I finally see problem - you have typo in `date=` - it should be `data=` with `a` instead of `e`

Comment: @furas thank you very much, hahaha a small typo made me stuck for 3 days, I am really appreciate your help